# Would Stack Overflow provide an IT freelance platform?

Tags: feature-request

I think Stack Overflow could provide a freelance service for the ones who needs an instant answer or instant troubleshooting.

Stack Overflow has all what it takes to be the number one world's freelance platform in IT related fields.

Comment: A community haggling over business transactions is antithetical to a cooperative community of volunteers helping build a knowledge base

Comment: We already have squabbles about *rep points* - just imagine the amount of grief getting money involved will bring. How would you moderate that? Also please note that we can afford to answer at our leisure and enforce guidelines in part because we do not charge anyone. Also, a paying customer is right even if they don't know what an `if` statement is or asks you about an NPE, you cannot demand to do proper research, tag or format correctly (well, one can try and see how well their business will fare) from them - and this is really horrifying to think about.

Comment: Don't we have precisely this already, except offered entirely for free? How do you think it would improve the platform by charging money?

Comment: @CodyGray: by charging money, you would change the dynamic of who controls content. Currently, it is the community who vets the quality and appropriateness of the question, but once changed into a fee-for-service, it is those paying the fee who would decide on the appropriateness and importance of the question (by say, offering more money for an acceptable answer). This would increase leverage for those asking low-quality and low-attention questions, and would undoubtedly improve the situation for this small sub-group of people. The overall quality of the site, though, would suffer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You were answering my question of how it would improve the platform by charging money? :-) Also, as long as there were diamonds around, I disagree with your prediction of who would control the content.

Answer (score 20):

For the love of all things holy, please Lord no.

One of the main reasons that the site succeeds compared to other similar programming "help" sites and is as popular as it is, is because the quality of questions and answers are curated by the users so that high quality and canonical questions and answers rise to the top and are easy to find and to use. Once you add money into the mix and start curating questions based on fees and not quality, then site quality will plummet.

Also, there already *are* sites where you can hire a freelance programmer. Why should this site step into that field when it already exists and is quite mature? You're going to need to show a lot more benefit if you hope to convince others that your idea has merit because the downsides are huge and are obvious (to me anyway).

Comment: but the freelance platform will be separated from free platform so the user here has 2 options: ask a good question and keep improving his/her score or use freelance platform and get paid assistance where stackoverflow would cut its fees. I know there is lots of freelance platform such as upwork, but stackoverflow could be much better than those.

Comment: @CYREX: if you have a great business plan for this idea, then why not go ahead and create this platform yourself and rake in the profits? But how would it be any different from any other Programmer-For-Hire platform? What would distinguish it? It is separate from SO as you state, and so it would be its own business.

Comment: ok. delete the question or close it. one thing sure about stackoverflow is not for

Comment: We don’t want a community of users who want to be paid for their help.

Comment: Re *"...site quality will plummet"*: That is what happened to the [hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) (not direct monetary transactions, but free memberships for answers)